# FlutterFlow calendar Week Start from JSON

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterflow

I have a JSON that has a field called {"startDayOfWeek":"Sunday"}. Is it possible to read this JSON and depending on its value show the calendar with the correct start day of the week?